# base64.java image to string

Tags: java, android, image, base64

I am trying to use the base64.java to convert and image into a string using

```
String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(bitmap, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

The problem is it underlines .DEFAULT saying DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field. Now I see in every example I found this is what they use, so why isn't it working when I try it?

the whole function that it is in looks like

```
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // hide video preview

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);  
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
        String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);        
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Tyler

Answer (score 2):

Import android.util.base64 instead of the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64?

Answer (score 1):

try using the `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64` class with only two methods `String encode(byte[] binary)` and `byte[] decode(String s)`

This may a) not be for android and b) be removed in a future release of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct Base64 class? Based on you code sample it should be android.util.Base64 (check what you got in your imports).

Comment: how could I check my imports? I was just copy and pasting the base64.java into the src file

Comment: @TylerM You can check what you are importing by looking at the top of your source file. Depending on how your IDE is set up, it may be collapsed. If when you look at the top there is a single line saying "import com..." with a plus to the left, click the plus and you will see what all you are importing

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks just like mine where I have that implemented. Only thing I can think to check is make sure you are importing android.util.Base64, and these APIs were added in API 8, so if your target is below that then you will have problems.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that the android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManaifest.xml is as least 8